# GraphQL Query to Get Data Two Different Tables

Tags: sql, graphql, graphql-js

I have two tables `a` and `b`. `a` have `id` and `age` fields. `b` have `id`, `pid`, and `name` fields. `b.pid` has a foreign key relationship with `a.id`. How can I get `age` and `name` from these tables using a GraphQL query? Tables are created using SQL.

Comment: Note that table have _columns_ not fields. And never store age, (most) people become older every year. Instead store date of birth.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an SQL question rather than a GraphQL question. If you need to get the `name` and `age`, your GraphQL query should look something like this:

```
query MyQuery {
    profile {
        name
        age
    }
}
```

But the real issue is how you design and implement your GraphQL API so this query works as expected. In that case, you may use a `JOIN` statement to retrieve the data within your `profile` resolver.

```sql
SELECT a.age, b.name
FROM a INNER JOIN b
ON a.id = b.pid
```